# unzip archive that is split into multiple volumes in R

Tags: r, zip, unzip

**Background**

I am creating an R script that is supposed to download .zip files, then unzip them and move the content into the right places of a directory.

The problem the places where I have to upload the data to has a file size limit so that I have to split the archive into multiple volumes.

**Example**

I am looking for something like

```
file <- 'myfile.zip001' # There is also 'myfile.zip002', 'myfile.zip003' and 'myfile.zip004'
unzip(file)
```

where I just unpacked this split archive in a certain directory. Is this possible?

PS I am not sure how to make reproducible example for this one. If you have suggestions, please let me know.

Comment: What mechanism are you using to split the zip file into multiple files? `zipsplit` or just `split`?

Comment: I've split them with 7-zip but I can use other ways if that would make it workable.

Comment: I didn't know that 7zip provided a way to split `.zip` (non 7z)` files. My guess is that you'll need to get all of the numbered files and then extract them together. (I'm not familiar with 7z's method of splitting and post-split extraction, perhaps it supports partial-archive extraction?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Borrowing from this [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/365643/how-to-unzip-split-files-on-os-x/517758#517758) and using files that were split with the base R `zip` function on a Mac.

```
# create split zip files
zip_name <- "foo.zip"

folder_path <- "folder/with/many/files"

# create zip with 100mb chunks
zip(zipfile = zip_name,
      files = list.files(folder_path,
                         full.names = T,
                         recursive = TRUE),
      flags = "-q -s 100m" )

## aggregate then unzip

# aggregate into a single zip
# -s == size of split, here we are setting it to zero so no splits
# --out == where should the files go?
# provide the file that ends in .zip to aggregate the split zip
# zip -s 0 [ZIP FILE from SPLIT] --out [AGGREGATED FILE]

agg_command <- "zip -s 0 foo.zip --out unsplit-foo.zip"

system(agg_command)

dir.create("foo_extract")

unzip(zipfile = "unsplit-foo.zip",exdir = "foo_extract")
```

Comment: Great idea to use system commands!

Comment: I haven't tested this but it should be possible (potentially more compatible with more OSs) to use the flags argument in `zip` if for whatever reason a user can't run system commands.